# opencv: saving images on mouseclick

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

So I've been messing around with opencv, and am trying to figure out how to capture an image on a mouse click. I've looked around a bit, but I just can't seem to find an answer. Here's the code that I have so far.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def captureFrame(event,frame):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.imwrite('pictures/testFrame.png',frame) # want to save frame here   

def main():
    cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',captureFrame)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that I want to pass the frame to the callback function captureFrame, but I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So I figured out how to do this and I'm posting the fix below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    count = 1

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',captureFrame,frame)

        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def captureFrame(event,x,y,flags,frame):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.imwrite('pictures/test.png',frame) # want to save frame here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, it is pretty unresponsive (as in I have to click multiple times to get a saved image, this may be because of a bad mouse though and i'll have to test that at a later time) and I haven't figured out why just yet. If anyone can explain why please do!